# displaying html form inputs horizontally

Tags: html, css, forms, input

i am trying to recreate the login form shown on tinypic's main page.

[image: login]

in html, i have the 3 elemnts like this:

```
E-Mail:
<input type="text" name="id" maxlength="30" value="" />
Password:
<input type="text" name="pw" maxlength="30" value="" />

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
```

i have tried putting them into separate divs,
using float:left with a unique class in css
but the code is really messy unreasonably long.
so essentially, i wanted to know if there was a simple way to achieve this layout with html and css.

thanks for the time!

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?  http://jsfiddle.net/2LYuX/

Comment: ops my bad, my div width for that section was too small for the inputs lulz

Comment: At least choose an answer and next time look a little deeper before posting a question

Comment: @iuliux i cant choose an answer right after i've posted a question..

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This CSS should work, though I haven't tested:

```
input { display: inline; }
```

Comment: that was short & neat

Answer (score 7):

Here is my solution: ( http://jsfiddle.net/HcppN/ )

HTML:

```
<label>E-Mail:</label>
<input type="text" name="id" maxlength="30" value="" />
<label>Password:</label> 
<input type="text" name="pw" maxlength="30" value="" />

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
```

CSS:

```
input, label {
    float:left;
    margin:5px;
}
```

I also recommend you to encapsulate the labels in `<label>` tags. You can even use the `for="inputId"` attribute, so that clicking on the label brings the input into focus.

Answer (score 3):

Just add `display:inline` to your input elements, as shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pMqsm/3/)

Answer (score -1):

Though there are already accepted and up voted answers, I just want to contribute a way to make a form horizontal without any kind of CSS. Using HTML table is an effective way to make a horizontal form.

**Example 1:**

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>First Name</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="fname" > </td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
   <td>Last Name</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="lname" > </td>
 </tr>
</table>

</form>
```

**Example 2:**

```
<form method="">
    
    <table>
     <tr>
       <td><input type="text" name="fname" ></td>
     
       <td><input type="text" name="lname" ></td>
        
       ........................
     </tr>
    </table>
    
</form>
```

My experience says, sometimes in different cases the CSS/class may not work or sometimes they may conflict ; but using an HTML table to make an HTML form is something like forcing to be what we want to be appear. Thank you.